# Waiting for resolving function in parents controller

Tags: angularjs

In parents controller $onInit() I'm waiting for resolving promise to set page title and get opid for list which has own controller.
This is from parent controller:

```
public $onInit = () => {
    this.swSubviewInfo.resolved.then((response: IDashboardResponseData) => {
        this.setGroupId(response.opid);
        this.updateTitle(response.objectName);
    });
}
```

I'd like to use state provider to wait for parent to resolve $onInit because correct opid is needed in initialization of child controller. Can sb give me example how to do that?
Below config file for child controller.

```
const state: IStateProvider = {
    controller: "groupMembersSubviewListController",
    controllerAs: "vm",
    template: require<string>("./groupMembersSubviewList.html"),
    resolve: {
        parent: ???
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please add some code snippet?

Comment: @NiralMunjariya Added.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not load the stuff in the $onInit. If you are in the $onInit, it is already "to late" for you to wait on promises.

From your example I assume you are using the ui-router of angularjs. There you have the possibility to resolve in a state (like you already try for the parent).

If you need promises to be loaded before a state actually works, I recommend to load it in the state via resolve (keep in mind, your page will wait with rendering until everything is resolved, so keep this as fast/short as possible)

And then declare the second state as child state from the parent. This way the second state only gets loaded until the resolve of the first one is done (In the newer versions activated by default).

A simplified version could look similar to this:

```
.state('parent', {
    templateUrl: 'file.html',
    controller: 'ParentController',
    url: '/url',
    resolve: {
        swSubviewInfo: () => {
            // do your loading stuff. Make sure to return a promise
        }
    },
})
.state('parent.child', {
    templateUrl: 'file2.html',
    controller: 'ChildController',
    url: '/child',
})
```

Also worth mentioning the parent resolve is now accessible in your child controller as binding, so you can access it with "swSubviewInfo"

Comment: Honestly I still have no clue how to exchange $onInit() into resolve {}. swSubViewInfo.resolved returns Promise

Comment: @PiotrP k, little bit weird since it is not a function. Where does this.swSubViewInfo come from? basically you pack your stuff you want to load from the $onInit to the resolve block of your parent state. And then just use the swSubviewInfo injection from the controller (e.g. ParentController(swSubviewInfo) { // your regular controller }

Answer (score 0):

This is design problem. The purpose of controller/view-model in MV* paradigm is to bind model to view, it should contain only presentation logic.

The fact that the logic listed in parent controller is demanded somewhere else suggests that a controller contains business logic that doesn't belong there (so-called 'fat controller' problem).

`swSubviewInfo` should be moved to a service and/or a resolver. Since resolvers resolve to promise values, it makes sense to return a promise from it:

```
resolve: {
    parent: (/* any service swSubviewInfo comes from */) => swSubviewInfo.resolved
}
```